# rename elif in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, grammar, cpython

I was recently playing a bit around with adding some optional statement names in python and that worked fine until i got to the if statement and I added an optional name for else and elif:

```
if_stmt = 'if' test ':' suite ('elif' test ':'suite)* ['else' ':' suite] |  'wenn' test ':' suite ('andernfalls' test ':'suite)* ['sonst' ':' suite]
```

then it compiled without errors, but when I ran a test with wenn and andernfalls and the Interpreter threw the error:

```
SystemError: unexpected token in 'if' statement: andernfalls
```

And every other Addition I made worked great. So why can´t I add other else and elif and how could I do?

I´m modifying the most recent python 2.7 code from the python website

EDIT
My test code is:

```
x = 1
y = 2
wenn x > y:
    print 1
andernfalls x < y:
    print 2
sonst:
    print 3
```

The file i was adding the line at the top to was the Grammar file in the Grammar directory of the python source code

Comment: Just to be complety clear: You are editing CPython's grammar and attempting to rename `if`, `elif`, and `else` to `wenn`, `andernfalls`, and `sonst`?

Comment: that seems like something that would be hardcoded in multiple places... I find it unlikely you could change something like that in a single place and have it work seamlessly.

Comment: Show us the code you tried to run. Also, how did you modify the interpreter? What specific files did you change, and how?

Comment: @ChristianDean to add the optional way of using if elif and else with wenn andernfalls and sonst

Comment: @Aaron for every other statement i added options to it worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`else` and `elif` have some special-case handling inside the AST generation code:

```c
static stmt_ty
ast_for_if_stmt(struct compiling *c, const node *n)
{
    ...
    /* s[2], the third character in the string, will be
       's' for el_s_e, or
       'i' for el_i_f
    */
    if (s[2] == 's') {
        ...
    }
    else if (s[2] == 'i') {
        ...
        if (TYPE(CHILD(n, (n_elif + 1))) == NAME
            && STR(CHILD(n, (n_elif + 1)))[2] == 's') {
            ...
```

You'll have to modify `ast_for_if_stmt` in [`Python/ast.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/ast.c#L2805) to change that handling.

Comment: Didnt work perfect, i changed the if statement to if (s[2] == 's' || s[2] == 'n')
and the else if  to else if (s[2] == 'i' || s[2] == 'd') but when i have x = 2 and y = 2 in my example code it should go to sonst and print 3 but it doesnt any idea why @user2357112

Comment: @lokilocus: What happens instead of printing 3?

Comment: There's another `else` special case in the `elif` handling you may have missed: `STR(CHILD(n, (n_elif + 1)))[2] == 's'`.